# Keyboard showing over textInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My code

```
return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
      style={styles.container}>

      <Header navigation={navigation}/>
      <TimeBar/>
      <View style={{height:RFValue(1),backgroundColor:'#C4C4C4'}}/>
      <Main/>
      <Form/>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
```

Here is the problem. The keyboard is showing over the textInput[image]

Comment: Please add your styles and the inner components definitions/styling too

Comment: So my inner components & stylings play a role in this? That's enough for me to debug the error. Thanks.

Comment: yes I think that you will need to add a keyboardVerticalOffset based on your header, TimeBar, View total height, but I can't really tell without knowing styles/structure of them